# Is it possible to filter both 'lava_rapido' and 'lava-rapido' using a simple REGEX?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to create a Google Analytics filter that helps me see data only for these url patterns:

http://www.xpto.com.br/local/lava-rapido

http://www.xpto.com.br/street/lava-rapido/lava-jato

http://www.xpto.com.br/em/state/lava-rapido

http://www.xpto.com.br/em/state_city/lava-rapido

http://www.xpto.com.br/local/state/cityname/lava_rapido/C404597429595E595D/xpto.html

Anybody could help me with that?

Thanks,

Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the header, here's the regex:

```
lava[-_]rapido
```

This allows either an underscore `_` or dash `-`.  You usually have to escape dashes `-` so they don't become ranges, but if a dash is at the beginning of a character class `[-ABC]`, you don't have to.

To match any of the above urls (with dash or underscore), use this (`urlPattern1|urlPattern2|urlPattern3`):

```
http://www\.xpto\.com\.br/local/lava[-_]rapido|http://www\.xpto\.com\.br/street/lava[-_]rapido/lava-jato|http://www\.xpto\.com\.br/em/state/lava[-_]rapido|http://www\.xpto\.com\.br/em/state_city/lava[-_]rapido|http://www\.xpto\.com\.br/local/state/cityname/lava_rapido/C404597429595E595D/xpto\.html
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the exact match:

```
http://www\.xpto.com.br\/(local|street|em)(\/(state|state\_city))?(\/cityname)?/(lava-rapido|lava_rapido)/?(lava-jato)?([A-Z0-9]*/[a-z0-9]*\.html)?
```

Tested in http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

This will match _ or -

```
lava[_\-]rapido
```